# Displaying JSON in Ruby on Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

I am new to Ruby on Rails,I am doing a college project, I have a load of json from a rb file from a get request

```
               {"amount":"0.00000000","currency":"BTC"}
               {"amount":"590.69","currency":"USD"}
               {"amount":"432.93","currency":"EUR"}
```

What I want to do is display the Json on a View, but I want the controller to do the heavy work and use good practice..Any suggestions?

Comment: how you want to display ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the `render` method in your controllers, and then pass in the `:json` option, like so:

```
render json: @hash_or_anything_you_want_to_display_as_json
```